Epsilon delta proof for $\frac{x^2 +1}{x+1} $ when x goes to infinity.
I need help in proving the following limt
$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} = \infty$
Here I need to choose N such that $\forall{x}, x>N$  such that  $\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} > M$
I stuck here  $\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} > \frac{1}{x+1}$
Thank you

@DavidK sorry my bad. it is a typo. I have to choose a N such that it satisfy the definition and I want t get a inequality between N and M

What you need to show is that, for any given $M>0$, there exists some $N>0$ such that, for $x>N$, you have that $\dfrac{x^2+1}{x+1} > M$. Noting that for $x>-1$ we have $\dfrac{x^2+1}{x+1} > x-1$, you can simply take $N = M+1$.
